# Resizing an image using PIL to maintain original aspect ratio?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, aspect-ratio

The program runs as expected, but it is always extended vertically and compressed horizontally.
I've attached the method where I resize the image and the main function.
Can't figure out what the problem is!

```
from PIL import Image

def resize(image, new_width=100):
    width, height = image.size                           
    ratio = width / height / 1.65                        
    new_height = int(ratio * new_width)                  
    resized_img = image.resize((new_width, new_height))  
    return resized_img                                   


def main(new_width=100):
    path = input("Enter a valid pathname to an image: ")           
    try:
        image = PIL.Image.open(path)
    except:
        print(path, "is not a valid pathname to an image.")
        return

    new_img_data = convert_chars(grayscale(resize(image)))

    pixel_count = len(new_img_data)
    ascii_img = "\n".join(new_img_data[i:(i + new_width)] for i in range(0, pixel_count, new_width))
    print(ascii_img)

    with open("ascii_image.txt", "w") as f:                    
        f.write(ascii_img)

main()
```

Comment: why are you dividing by `1.65` in `ratio = width / height / 1.65`? why can't you just use `ratio = width/height`?

Comment: @Driftr95 this was to account for the size of the characters

Comment: I still think the additional number messes up the ratio and would distort the image, but it should be `ratio = height/width` like J_H said. using `2.75` instead of `1.65` might resolve the issue for now, but you should check by testing on images with various aspect ratios to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't make sense:

```
    ratio = width / height ...                        
    new_height = int(ratio * new_width)
```

Imagine width is 100 and you had been dividing by unity.
Then new_height should recover the original height, right?
But instead we have width squared over height.
It's upside-down.

---

Please fix things up and then [show us](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)
the improved code.

Comment: I don't understand this, can you show me what you mean?

Comment: For simplicity I changed 1.65 to 1. I'm just doing algebra, substituting in `ratio`: new_height = int(width * (1/height) * new_width), which gives us int(width**2 * (1/height)). Your ratio is fine. You will need to properly derive new_height from an expression that contains ratio.

Comment: so actually, I was able to fix it by changing 1.65 to 2.75!

Comment: Now run it on half-size, quarter-size, eighth-size input images to verify.

Comment: not sure exactly how, but it is working! thank you!